# Rails delayed job multithreading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process, delayed-job

Is there any way to run same method parallel in background using delayed job gem?
For example i have one method `assign_tasks` which creates 4K to 6K records in database, when called multiple times same method for different objects is there any way to accomplish this execution faster or execute all calls parallelly?
It takes hours to complete 3 to 4 method calls to complete.

```
def assign_tasks
  #some conditions to find matched users here
  #if matched create new record for a user
  users.each do |u|
    task = Task.new(user_id: u.id)
    task.save
  end
end

@project.delay.assign_tasks
```

Comment: can you include the code of your delayed job, or at least the time-using bits of it?

Comment: @jad added pseudo code.

Comment: Did you investigate what exactly takes so long? Is it loading the users because of the complex condition? Is it loading all users into memory because there are too many? Or is each `Task.new` or saving the record taking so long? If so why?

Comment: Note that each `save` call is wrapped in a separate transaction which can cause a lot of overhead. You can speed this up by combining multiple calls in one transaction. In addition, you might want to take at look at [`insert_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all) which can create multiple records in a single database query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/) you could add a method to your `User` model like this

```
def assign_task
  Task.create(user_id: id)
end
```

and process it delayed like this in your original method:

```
def assign_tasks
  users.find_each { |user| user.delay.assign_task }
end
```

Then the task generation for each user will happen in the background and – when there are enough workers – in parallel.

Btw there are other tools that support processing jobs in the background – the most common nowerdays is Sidekiq. They all have a slightly different syntax and different dependencies. Depending on your Ruby on Rails version and your requirements you might even want to use [`ActiveJob`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) which ships with Rails per default.

Comment: I'm already using delayed job as suggested by you but it takes hours to assign_tasks if called for 3-4 times, is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: When I look at your code in the question then No, you do not use it as I suggested. You have one job creating all tasks sequentially. I suggested in my example to create the tasks in parallel which should be much faster when you are running multiple workers.

Comment: The method names are very similar which could cause some confusion. It might be better to rename the latter to something like `schedule_task_assignments` which would also communicate the method's intent.

Comment: @spickermann i tried your suggestion it still takes same time to assign tasks to 4k users, no improvements in performance of assignment job

Comment: Are you sure that DelayedJob is configured in configured correctly in your environment? It is, for example, not uncommon to tell DelayedJob to work inline and not in the background in test and development environment and only work in the background on production.